# Request payload not found in network tab in chrome devtools

Tags: sails.io.js, konga

In the https://github.com/pantsel/konga application, I created a connection, but not found the **payload data** in the network tab.
I saw the request to "/api/kongnode", the only request was found here.
Some data had been filled in the form, and they must be submitted to the backend server.
But why can't I see the Request payload? Is these a way to see it? Because I want to make the request with CURL tool.

[image]

```
Request URL: http://kong-test.io/api/kongnode
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 22 Mar 2021 08:21:02 GMT
ETag: W/"2f8-mBk5v5XkPHQmmd8i9J12nw"
Server: nginx/1.17.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
authorization: Bearer eywtqweterefa1NiJ9.OQ.rQDZh4asdfasfd
Cache-Control: no-cache
connection-id: 1
Cookie: io=k-WKMasdfasdf
Host: kong-test.io
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://kong-test.io/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537.36
```

[image]
[image]